# Could not find method File() for arguments

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

I'm having this error while running my flutter app, there is something wrong with my settings.gradle file.

My android sdk location:"F:\AndroidSdk"
My flutter sdk location:"F:\FlutterSdk"

```
...................ERROR.......................
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'E:\rider_app-master\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Could not find method File() for arguments [E:\rider_app-master\android, local.properties] on settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My setting.gradle file (there is no error but still can't run my app)

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile =  File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties =  Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Comment: Missing `new`: `def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")`

Comment: i tried adding "new keword "but still not working..

Comment: Define "still not working". Same error message? Different error message? If so, what's the new error message?

Comment: same error as mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and (for some reason) the .gradle files in the project didn't have the "new" keyword when creating objects.

Open your build.gradle (in android/app) and settings.gradle, look for Properties(), GradleException(), File() etc and add "new" before. That solved it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).